# Android Popup Window dismisses when clicked outside

Tags: android, popupwindow

I was hoping to get an answer to my problem I have at the moment.

I have a class which extends popup window. It works fine except I don't want the window to dismiss when I click outside of the window.

At the moment I have `setOutsideTouchable(false);` but this just stops events outside the window, it still dismisses the popup.

A dialog has `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`, is there something similar I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Here's my answer[1]! And the question is [question].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406339/avoiding-popupwindow-dismissal-after-touching-outside/30586418#30586418
  [question]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406339/avoiding-popupwindow-dismissal-after-touching-outside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so fixed in the end.

First made the main layout which the popup sits on a relative layout. Then placed a full screen blank layout on top which I made invisible and transparent.

Then show when the popup is shown, set the full screen panel visible with `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and hide when popup is hidden with `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Also need to return true from an on touch listener for the layout with (To stop touch events passing back to the main layout):

```
blocker.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
return true;
}
});
```

And give the popup window the properties:

```
setTouchable(true);
setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Cheers

Comment: can you explain more exactly how did you create the layout?

Comment: when you're cruising stackoverflow and suddenly realise the answer you need is written by an old colleague - cheers Joss

Answer (score 0):

What are you using this `PopupWindow` for? It sounds like you use it in a more `Dialog`-ish way.

That being said you'll probably have to look into using [`setTouchInterceptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setTouchInterceptor%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) and then creating your own [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) which you will use to check where the touch was performed (on the Popup or not).

Comment: Hi, I am using the popup window with a carousel and several linear layouts inside. It seems to work best for what I need to do aside from this issue I have.