# How to dismiss a pop_up window when clicking outside?

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow

I want to know how to close a pop_up window once the user clicks outside it, I had a look at [PopupWindow - Dismiss when clicked outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside/) but without any luck, and I tried that code:

```
pw.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
pw.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
          {
           if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
                {
                    pw.dismiss();
                    return true;
                 }
            return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: I think you forget to add  `@Override` before `onTouch(....)` method used. try this way  `@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { ........}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.Hope it works :)

solution 1:

```
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.update();
```

If this dont work.Then you can try this out.

solution 2:

You can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` which will close the dialog if you touch outside of the dialog.

Something like,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
  dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Or if your Dialog in non-model then,

1 - Set the flag-FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL for your dialog's window attribute

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

2 - Add another flag to windows properties,, FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH - this one is for dialog to receive touch event outside its visible region.

3 - Override onTouchEvent() of dialog and check for action type. if the action type is 'MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE' means, user is interacting outside the dialog region. So in this case, you can dimiss your dialog or decide what you wanted to perform. view plainprint?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
        System.out.println("TOuch outside the dialog ******************** ");  
               this.dismiss();  
       }  
       return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so fixed in the end.

First made the main layout which the popup sits on a relative layout. Then placed a full screen blank layout on top which I made invisible and transparent.

Then show when the popup is shown, set the full screen panel visible with `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and hide when popup is hidden with `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Also need to return true from an on touch listener for the layout with (To stop touch events passing back to the main layout):

```
blocker.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
return true;
}
});
```

And give the popup window the properties:

```
setTouchable(true);
setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Cheers

Comment: This is an exact copy+paste of [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8398317/1682559)... And it is the opposite of what the OP wants..

Answer (score 0):

you should'nt set the BackgroundDrawable to null, because that kills the OnTouchListener ;
you should replace `pw.setBackgroundDrawable(null);`  by  `pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable())`

Comment: `BitmapDrawable()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Better use a dialog Fragment for the same. It is made for the popup functionality and closes by default on pressing outside the dialog Fragment or using the hard back button.