# Don't dismiss PopupWindow when clicking outside, only when the Close button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, popup, popupwindow, dismiss

I have a PopupWindow with a Close-Button, and I only want to close the PopupWindow when this Close-Button is clicked. In addition, I don't want to underlying Activity-View to be affected by any touches.

This has been asked before: [Android Popup Window dismisses when clicked outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355905/android-popup-window-dismisses-when-clicked-outside). But since it's a question and answer of three years ago (2011) I was wondering if there is a better solution for this now or I should indeed use the accepted answer's method.

Comment: I got this problem too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do both:

```
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255773/android-prevent-button-click-outside-of-popupwindow) out

Answer (score 0):

try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577596/issue-dismissing-popup-window) OR one of the below code

```
pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

**OR**

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
    // Tapped outside so we finish the activity
    this.finish();
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: The link: This is the opposite of what I want, since he wants to dismiss when clicking outside. The `setOutsideTouchable(false)`: This helps to ignore onClicks / onTouches of my Activity's View, but it still "dismisses" (set to the background without being able to access it anymore) the PopupWindow. About the last one: How is finished the Activity when I click outside the PopupWindow (the same activity in which this PopupWindow is created and displayed) helping me. :S To clarify: I want to do nothing (ignore all touch events and still display the PopupWindow) when clicking outside the popup.

Comment: `final PopupWindow popUpReject = new PopupWindow(popuplayoutReject, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, false);
                    popUpReject.setOutsideTouchable(false);`


try this code..

Comment: have you tried this `pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);` ? this is as simple of what you want. It will dismiss all the screen touch expect to the pop up dialog & set popup dismiss to onclick of your close button.

Comment: Yeah I did. However, even with `popup.setOutsideTouchable(false)`, the PopupWindow still disappears and I'm also still getting a  `InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`-Warning when I click outside of the PopupWindow.