# Android - Prevent button click outside of PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I've spent a while trying to get this to work, looked for similar solutions online, but none seem to work. I need my PopupWindow to only be dismissed on the click of the generate button, not by clicking outside the window. Anyone encountered this issue before?

```
private void LoadRAMSPopup() {
    mainLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(150);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View ramsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_rams, null);
    final PopupWindow popupRAMS = new PopupWindow(
            ramsView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        popupRAMS.setElevation(5.0f);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            popupRAMS.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            popupRAMS.setOutsideTouchable(false);
            popupRAMS.setFocusable(true);
            popupRAMS.update();

            Button btnGenerate = (Button) ramsView.findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate);
            btnGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateRAMSActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    popupRAMS.dismiss();
                    mainLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting up **popupRAMS.setFocusable(false)**. removes unnecessary touch required to make popup window disappear. So please replace

```
popupRAMS.setFocusable(true);
```

with

```
popupRAMS.setFocusable(false);
```

Also try to add

```
popupRAMS.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: This works to a certain extent as it doesn't allow the popup to be dismissed on an outside click, however I also need to prevent everything in the view underneath from being clickable that the popup is on top of.

Comment: In that case I dont think your pop will work. You have to manage this with a single layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
popupRAMS.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)));
popupRAMS.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every other solution and the one that worked forme was setting "false" on the constructor

```
mDiscountPopUp = new PopupWindow(discountPopUpView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false); // Creation of popup
```